# looking for a replacement to the descriptor "deep" to describe experience

Tags: single-word-requests

Every member of our team has deep operating experience in healthcare.

Comment: "deep" -> "extensive" I guess.  But I don't know what "operating" means here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I've changed the question's tag because your original tag [tag:word-choice] requires you to provide a list of words to choose from. If that was your intention, please feel free to [roll back the change](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/411035/revisions) and [edit] the question to add your list. Alternatively, have a look at the [info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) page for [tag:single-word-requests] for tips on making such requests.

Comment: Replacement how/why? What are you looking for? Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah "extensive" is the word to replace deep for sure but I think you could remove the term "operating" as it seems out of place and unnecessary, but it's hard to tell without knowing exactly what point your trying to get across. If you are actually referring to something more specific like surgical experience I would say "...extensive surgical experience." The "...in health care" part being seemingly redundant in that case as it's clearly implied by the first part of the sentence.

If you're not trying to be that specific, the sentence could also work well as:

... extensive experience working in health care.

Cheers